# Visual Studio 2012 recent projects not updated in taskbar

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio pinned to the taskbar. When clicking on the icon with the mouse right button, a list of recent projects and solutions in shown.

This used to work OK, but from some time now, the list is not being updated. I always see same projects and solutions under *Recent*, although I have worked with newer projects lately.

How can I fix it?

I'm running Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 on Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: Did you try to unpin and pin again?

Comment: Hey @Micha, already tried it, but didn't work.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. When I launch visual studio I can go to File menu and see an updated list of recent files and projects but when I right click on the task bar icon the recent list is not reflecting the most recent projects. I am running VS 2012 premium on windows 8.1

Comment: @JimScott Let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- Close all VS instance
- Right click on the Taskbar.
- Click Properties
- Go to the Jump Lists Tab
- Uncheck Store recently opened programs
- Uncheck Store and display recently opened items in Jump Lists
- Click Apply/Ok
- Wait a moment
- Check Store recently opened programs
- Check Store and display recently opened items in Jump Lists
- Wait a moment
- Open your VS solution and it should now appear in the Jump List.
- This worked as a fix for VS 2012 professional with Win 8 Pro

Comment: I needed to remove the solution from the visual studio recent list first.

Comment: This solution plus Kijana's additional step appears to work in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I had tried to manually remove the entire content of "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations", but recent files were still not updated on the taskbar icon. Weirdly, unchecking/apply/checking the "Store recently..." items also empties the entire AutomaticDestinations folder, but it must do something else too, as it works! Downside to this solution is that the extra items that were available as a right-click on the VS icon have now gone, I remember 2 of them: "Safe Mode" and "Show Activity Log" which were shown just above the "Recent" section.

Comment: I also had to bump up my number of recent items to get this working. Thanks for the solution @Jeff2001!

Comment: Cheers! This also works for Visual Studio 2013, although the problem appears to reappear from time to time.

BTW the section needed for Windows 7 is labelled:
Taskbar properties -> Start Menu -> Privacy -> [Tick boxes] etc...

Comment: Note that if you have VS set up to automatically open the last solution, then this solution will not appear in the list. You'll need to open a solution manually for it to appear in the recent items list.

Comment: In Win10 this is located in Settings - Personalization - Start, or simply search for "jump list".

Comment: This method works for Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This last check was the solution for me on Windows 10. Hope it helps someone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just installed VS 2019 in January this year (2020) so there's no explanation for why this isn't yet resolved by MS; if you do research, you'll see years old info indicating they were "working on a fix".  I searched for info in the last year to ensure I got back the most relevant answers and this came up first because there was activity in 2019.  I'm on Win 10 and none of the suggestions above helped.

As a last resort, I manually deleted the old projects from the right-click list and that freed up space for newer files.  I then opened 2 of my most recent files and they now appear.  Better than nothing.  Meh.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have more pinned projects than recent projects.  At least for my setup in VS2017, I had VS set up to display 10 project, but had more than 10 projects pinned.

To change that:

- Go to Options --> Environment --> General --> "Items to show in recently used file list" textbox.  This impacts the Recent Files and Recent Projects list count.
- Go to File --> Start Page.  If that Pinned list of projects is the same or more than the configuration, then no recents will show up.

It is definitely debatable if Recent list *should* contain the Pinned items, but that is how it works.  Your truly recent projects will be listed after your pinned projects.