# How to set projects to the recent view in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Recently, I have upgraded my visual studio from 2012 to 2013 and since then I can't get the projects that I have used to the recent view. Before it was automatically - when I open a project it is pined to the Recent view.

[image]

The projects you see there are not recent - those projects were opened some months ago, and since then I have opened lots of projects and non of them are appearing in the recent view, why is that? How can I fix it so I will have shortcuts to the recent projects I have used? Can it be because I am using the visual studio trial right now?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio, you can choose `Tools->Options`. You have an option for the number of items in the recently used list. You can change the change the "items shown in recently used list" to 24 (the maximum).

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General (Items shown in recently used lists)

Also check [Visual Studio 2010, “File > Recent Projects and Solutions” is not a active !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552535/visual-studio-2010-file-recent-projects-and-solutions-is-not-a-active)

The second solution provided by Yetti there is helpful:

> **Solution To #2**: This one is a little bit more complicated because it could be a number of things.
>
> 1. First, I would make sure you have the number you want for the "Recent files" options in Tools > Options > Environment > General.
> 2. If you already had that, check the registry location and make sure you actually have entries here since this is where VS pulls it from. 
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectMRUList
>      . The 10.0 is for VS 2010.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552535/visual-studio-2010-file-recent-projects-and-solutions-is-not-a-active). If there's nothing
>      there then your recent projects aren't being saved properly.
> 3. You could try calling `Devenv /ResetSettings` to reset the VS settings. More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
> 4. Finally it could be due to a Windows Explorer setting which hides recent files. This is a possibility because VS takes its directions
>      from the same place with regards to recent files. You would need to
>      make sure
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>      "NoRecentDocsHistory" is zero. More info on this possible solution as
>      well as other ideas to this problem can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/8886195e-0ac2-4712-8543-4a59a7cee93b).

Comment: This did not solve my issue; however, this article did. Hope it helps someone as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438798/visual-studio-2012-recent-projects-not-updated-in-taskbar

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use something like [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-delete-and-clear-recent-items-in-windows-7-jump-lists/)? I'd recommend you clear all recent items jump list files. Visual Studio may not know about version update and still use the jump list from the previous version!

Answer (score 1):

you can try look it in you regedit

open a command window 
type regedit
then find here

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\FileMRUList
```

this stores the recent opened projects of vs2012

Comment: I see there the recent projects, but why I don't see them on the recent view in the right click on visual studio?

Comment: maybe beacuse vs2013 uses different value of regedit

Answer (score 0):

To me, I just needed to open the VS solution by double-clicking on the solution in the Windows File Explorer.  (I.e. *not* first open Visual Studio, then open the solution from the recent list within Visual Studio).